# How to view Message list in HornetQ

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, message-driven-bean

We have limited the number of maxSession to 5
**@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "5")**
If more than 5 concurrent request comes, then it has to wait in the queue. Is there any option to view the number of waiting messages in the queue as a list and manage the queue. Is there any API to view and manage the queue. For example, if a JMS message is waiting for long time, using queue management we can re-initiate message or we can drop the message.

Answer (score 5):

JMS Browsers are made to do that.

You can also use the Management API to do that.

Also, the issue with you doing that is going to be concurrency.

The message may be gone by the time you use anything to list the message.

Also, have you looked at expired messages? if you want a timeout for the message, you could set expiration and listen to the expiry queue. That would be a better design for your application.

Comment: hi Clebert, is there any GUI for viewing Hornetq messages and can you tell how to connect jms browser to hornetq.

Comment: JMS Browser is part of the JMS API. There's a lot of information on the JMS Tutorial.  As for viewing the messages, you can use the list methods on the JMX methods.

Comment: if you don't have any more questions, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: hi clebert, can you tell me which will be better option for hornetq management, Core Management API,JMS Management API and Using Management Via JMX,

Comment: It really depends on your use case vairam.. there's no preferred way